# Generic-based function no longer works

Tags: generics, swift

This function worked in a prior version of Xcode6 (with `array: T[]` as the declaration).

```
func shuffle<T>(array: [T]) -> Void {
    for i in 0..<(array.count - 1) {
        let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count - i))) + i
        let tmp = array[i]
        array[i] = array[j]
        array[j] = tmp
    }
}
```

Under beta 4 it's now telling me that the lvalues of the last two assignments are not identical to `T`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Array was changed to a true **value type**. That means that it is always copied when being assigned to a new variable or passed into a method. You are trying to modify that copy which would end up doing nothing so the compiler stops you by making the `array` immutable.

To fix this, you can define `array` as an inout paramater:

```
func shuffle<T>(inout array: [T]) -> Void {
```

**Note:** You will then need to put an `&` before the array being passed into shuffle `shuffle(&anArray)`

But you may want to consider having your function return a new copy instead:

```
func shuffle<T>(var array: [T]) -> [T] {
```

This will allow it to work in a mulithreaded environment safely and it will allow passing in Optionals to your function.

Comment: Since OP is modifying `array` in place, that second one would need to be `func shuffle<T>(var array: [T]) -> [T] {`.

Comment: Thanks @NateCook, I was kind of just assuming that the implementation would be somewhat different, but your suggestion makes the transition easier. I updated my answer.